# Best domain hosting for Google App Engine / Google Apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

Any thoughts on the current "best" domain host for Google App Engine / Google Apps?

My criteria:

- nice, usable UI (i.e., not GoDaddy)
- support for wildcard CNAME (also not GoDaddy), to interop with wildcard mappings in App Engine
- a good API for purchasing, changing DNS records programmatically
- a good, physical DNS infrastructure (e.g., good DNS response times, uptime globally)
- awareness of Google Apps (e.g., all the MX, etc. set up automatically) is a plus

So far, name.com looks pretty good, though I have no idea about their physical infrastructure.

Any comments/recommendations?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/133242)

Comment: Ever considered AWS Route 53?